# Can I put html inside a Symfony form button with Twig?

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm trying to put html inside a form button with twig like:

```
{{ form_widget(form.jiraStatus, {
        'label': '<i class="fa fa-bug"></i>Bug',
        'attr':{'class': 'btn btn-large btn-default btn-block' }
}) }}
```

But doing this, the rendeded button shows like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="SolveTask[taskTypesFormObj][bugStatus]"
    class="btn btn-large btn-default btn-block">
    &lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-bug&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;Bug
</button>
```

As you can see, the html inside the button is encoded. I tried to use the raw filter, but the effect is the same. There is a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to customise [your form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

> **Note:** This answer has been edited to be compatible with Symfony 2.8 3.x and 4.x. For older versions, please see the edit history.

A nice way to support icons in buttons is using form extensions. First create a form extension class that defines a new property *icon* that you can use in your forms:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ButtonTypeIconExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('icon', $options['icon']);
    }

    /**
     * @param FormView      $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array         $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['icon'] = $options['icon'];
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['icon' => null]);
        $resolver->setDefined(['icon']);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return ButtonType::class; // Extend the button field type
    }
}
```

Register this extension in your services.yml (or xml file). The alias must correspond with the string returned by the above  `getExtendedType()` method.

```
# Form extension for adding icons
foobar.form_extension.icon:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Form\Extension\ButtonTypeIconExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType }
```

Next, override your `form_div_layout.html.twig`. (See link above) You can now use `icon` as a variable in these themes. For buttons we override the `button_widget` block:

```
{% block button_widget -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' btn')|trim}) %}
    {% if label is empty -%}
        {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
            {% set label = label_format|replace({
                '%name%': name,
                '%id%': id,
            }) %}
        {%- else -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {% if icon|default %}
        {% set iconHtml = '<i class="fa ' ~ icon ~ '"></i> ' %}
    {% else %}
        {% set iconHtml = '' %}
    {% endif %}
    <button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>{{ iconHtml|raw }}{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</button>
{%- endblock button_widget %}
```

Finally, you can use the icon option in your template:

```
{{ form_widget(form.jiraStatus, {
    'icon': 'fa-bug',
    'label': 'Bug',
    'attr':{'class': 'btn btn-large btn-default btn-block' }
}) }}
```

Or in your form classes:

```
    $builder
        ->add('jiraStatus', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Bug',
                'icon' => 'fa-bug',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-large btn-default btn-block',
                ],
            ]
        );
```

Note: Is is generally better to add the icon in the template since icons are a matter of presentation, and your form classes should really be about buisness logic.

**Make it even more generic:**

By returning the FQCN of ButtonType in getExtendedType() we tell Symfony that we are extending all possible form elements that inherit from *ButtonType* such as *SubmitType*. Unfortunately there is no type we can use to target all possible form elements but we can add an extra extension that targets *FormType*. All form fields like input boxes and select elements inherit from this type. So if you want it to work with both form fields *and* buttons, I suggest the following:

Create an abstract class `abstract class AbstractIconExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension` with exactly the same content as above but leave out the `getExtendedType` method. Then create two classes that extend from this class (e.g. `FieldTypeIconExtension` and `ButtonTypeIconExtension`) which only contain the `getExtendedType` method. One returning the FQCN of `FormType` and the other returning the FQCN of `ButtonType`:

*Foo/BarBundle/Form/Extension/ButtonTypeIconExtension.php:*

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;

class ButtonTypeIconExtension extends AbstractIconExtension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return ButtonType::class;  // extend all buttons
    }
}
```

*Foo/BarBundle/Form/Extension/FieldTypeIconExtension.php:*

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;

class FieldTypeIconExtension extends AbstractIconExtension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;  // extend all field types
    }
}
```

Register these two classes in you services using the corresponding alias:

```
# Form extensions for adding icons to form elements
foobar.form_extension.button_icon:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Form\Extension\ButtonTypeIconExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType }
foobar.form_extension.form_icon:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Form\Extension\FieldTypeIconExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```

Now you can use the `icon` variable in other places in your form themes as well. For instance, to add icons to labels you can override the `form_label` block:

```
{% block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) -%}
        {% if not compound -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if icon|default %}
            {% set iconHtml = '<i class="fa ' ~ icon ~ '"></i> ' %}
        {% else %}
            {% set iconHtml = '' %}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ iconHtml|raw }}{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock form_label %}
```

And then add an icon to the label of that field in your form class:

```
$builder
    ->add('mytextfield', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'My fancy text field',
            'icon' => 'fa-thumbs-o-up'
        ]
    );
```

Comment: @Xatoo setDefaultOptions inside the form type extension doesn't exist anymore (and anywhere else as well) in Symfony 3. It's called configureOptions now. Works in Symfony 2.8 as well (and probably 2.7 as well, not sure when it was deprecated)

Comment: @MilesM. I'm currently working on this (Symfony 4.1.1), and it works just fine!

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for a simpler solution, just insert this into your [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes):

```
{%- block button_widget -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('btn-default') ~ ' btn')|trim}) %}
    {%- if label is empty -%}
        {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
            {% set label = label_format|replace({
                '%name%': name,
                '%id%': id,
            }) %}
        {%- else -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    <button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw }}</button>
{%- endblock button_widget -%}
```

You can then go ahead and insert HTML in your button label:

```
{{ form_widget(searchForm.search, {'label': '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>'}) }}
```

Comment: This worked for me albeit I shall be back it it disrupts the normal buttons. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

On Symfony 5.1, you can add html content into button label like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, { 'label': '<i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculate prices', 'label_html' : true })}}
```

You need to pass the option `"label_html" : true`

You can view the original Symfony/Twig code from *form_div_layout.html.twig* file to understand it:

```
{%- block button_widget -%}
    {%- if label is empty -%}
        {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
            {% set label = label_format|replace({
                '%name%': name,
                '%id%': id,
            }) %}
        {%- elseif label is not same as(false) -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    <button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>
        {%- if translation_domain is same as(false) -%}
            {%- if label_html is same as(false) -%}
                {{- label -}}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- if label_html is same as(false) -%}
                {{- label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain) -}}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain)|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
    </button>
{%- endblock button_widget -%}
```

Answer (score 3):

this is how I solved and tested with Symfony 4.
In twig template:

```
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}
<div class="class row">
    <div class="class col-sm-offset col-sm-10">
        <button name='create' type='submit' value='create' class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
        <button name='cancel' type='submit' value='cancel' class='btn btn-cancel' formnovalidate='formnovalidate'>Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
{{form_end(form)}}
```

In my PHP controller form I did not add any button but just input fields.

```
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($article)
        ->add('title',TextType::class, array(
            'data' => $article->getTitle(),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('body', TextareaType::class, array(
            'data' => $article->getBody(),
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->getForm();
```

What I did to check the form submission is:

```
if($form->isSubmitted() ){
    if($request->request->get('create') && $form->isValid()){
        $article = $form->getData();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($article);
        $entityManager->flush();
    } //l'alternativa può solo essere il cancel
    return $this->redirectToRoute('article_list');    
}
```

Hope this can help. Good to say that even the problem of buttons alignment is solved because `div` is not added for every button as form `add` method does.

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler solution might be to leave the buttons out of the form type and set `name` and `value` attributes. Then retrieve them as you would normal post parameters in the controller.

In your template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

<button name="clicked" value="saveDraft" class="btn btn-warning">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> Save as Draft
</button>
<button name="clicked" value="saveComplete" class="btn btn-warning">
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Save as Complete
</button>
```

Then in your controller

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $clicked = $request->request->get('clicked');
}
```