# Symfony/Twig - styling form widgets

Tags: css, forms, symfony, fonts, widget

I'm trying to make an ugly file upload button look like a nice font awesome icon.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-round mt-0 mb-0 uploadMediaTrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadMedia" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Upload Media">
        <i class="far fa-images"></i>
    </button>
    {{ form_widget(postForm.file, { 'attr': {'class': 'far fa-images'} } ) }}
</div>
```

Do you know how I can get the ugly button to look like the font awesome icon?  Seems like merely adding the font awesome classes doesn't work.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: You can use `form_widget` and set custom class in Twig (if you use that form in more than one place) or you can access `postForm.file.vars.*` and create your custom HTML. Use `{{ dump(variable) }}` to see what you can use.

Comment: Hide the `<input type="file"` and style the lable to your icon via css. So later the click on the lable will trigger and not the click on the input.

Comment: Hi Fabian, so do I have to add a label, and then add a click event to the label?

Comment: No the click will handle each browser automatically for you :) Read this short article about it https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/ or have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer with Form Themes and Form Extensions. This solution is compatible with Symfony 2.8.x and 4.x.

[Can I put html inside a Symfony form button with Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905939/can-i-put-html-inside-a-symfony-form-button-with-twig?answertab=active#tab-top)